# Is there a way to nest sed substitutions?

Tags: regex, sed

I want to change the format of every line in a file, and also run another substitution on one of the matched groups.

As an example, I could have a simple three-column CSV file (without escapes) that I wanted to put in another format.

```
sed -r 's/^([a-z]+),([a-z]+),([a-z]+)$/\1: \3 (\2)'
# would turn "comma,separated,values"
# into       "comma: values (separated)"
```

However, I *also* want to remove all the vowels from the second column, i.e. run `s/[aeiou]//g` on `\2`.

Is there a nice solution to this problem of nesting substitutions? Please assume that both substitutions are complicated, and that this was just an example.

My sed is not GNU sed version 4.0.

Comment: Can you not pipe one sed into a second one?

Comment: @inTide: I don't want to remove _all_ vowels, just those from the second column.

Comment: Right, so first sed you remove all vowels between commas and second sed you make first comma `: ` and second comma `()`.

Comment: @inTide: I'm looking for a solution that works for all formats and doesn't require me to write almost the same pattern twice. I know that `sed` has a lot of capabilities with dynamic range specification, but don't know how to use them for this problem.

Comment: So what version *is* your sed?

Comment: @Beta: I just posted the question here: [Which sed version is not GNU sed 4.0?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16350/which-sed-version-is-not-gnu-sed-4-0)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're better off with `awk` for this one, to make it easier to manipulate the fields.

```
echo "gaviidae,gruidae,picidae" | awk -F "," '{gsub(/[aeiou]/, "", $2); printf("%s: %s (%s)\n", $1, $3, $2)}'
```

outputs:

```
gaviidae: picidae (grd)
```

Comment: I don't know `awk`; is there a simple way to match in a way similar to `sed`? Your command seems to split on `,`, so it's not very general.

Comment: The field delimiter is set by the -F argument.  It accepts regular expressions, but not in the manner that you would write them for using backreferences.  I'll grant that awk isn't very helpful if your format requires more complex parsing to split into fields.

Answer (score 1):

This is cryptic (like almost any non-trivial sed) but it'll do the job. It takes advantage of the fact that you want the modified word to go at the end-- the same trick will work if you want it to go to some other position, but the command will be a little longer.

```
sed 'h;s/.*,([a-z]+),.*/(\1)/;s/[aeiou]//g;x;s/([a-z]+),[a-z]+,([a-z]+)/\1: \2 /;G;s/\n//'
```

Or in English: "save a copy in the hold buffer, kill all but the second word, strip out the vowels, swap the buffers, rearrange the words (dropping the middle one), add the other buffer onto the end, remove the new-line".